# when applying the BMA packages in R : Error in terms.formula(formula, special, data = data) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Tags: r

I am using the BMA packages in R (test.bic.surv) to estimating the Cox proportional model from a large  set of variables (100 base variables and about 60 lags for each of them). When I try the first set of testing with the following codes, it works.

```
x1<- x[,c(     "comprisk", "compriskL1", "compriskL2", "compriskL3", "compriskL4", "econrisk", "econrisk_1", "econrisk_2", "econrisk_3", "econrisk_4", "econrisk_5", "finrisk", "finrisk_1", "finrisk_2", "finrisk_3", "finrisk_4", "finrisk_5", "polrisk", "polrisk_1","polrisk_2","polrisk_3","polrisk_4","polrisk_5","polrisk_6","polrisk_7","polrisk_8","polrisk_9","polrisk_10","polrisk_11","polrisk_12")]

surv.t<- x$crisis1
cens<- x$cen1
test.bic.surv<- bic.surv(x1, surv.t, cens, factor.type=FALSE, strict=FALSE, nbest=2000)
```

However, whenever I tried to add in any more independent variables into x1 such as  "comprisk5L" or "econriskL1", the

```
test.bic.surv<- bic.surv(x1, surv.t, cens, factor.type=FALSE, strict=FALSE, nbest=2000)
```

showed me the error like this :

```
 "Error in terms.formula(formula, special, data = data) :    '.' in formula and no 'data' argument".
```

I have searched through the web for several days but couldn't figure out where was the problem . Can anyone please tell me what to do?? Thank you so much in advance!!!:)

Here is what the sample data looks like:

```
     crisis1 cen1 comprisk econrisk econrisk_1 econrisk_2 econrisk_3 econrisk_4
1         0    1     57.0     25.5        3.3        6.7        4.0        6.7
2         0    1     57.0     25.5        3.3        6.7        4.0        6.7
3         0    1     57.0     25.5        3.3        6.7        4.0        6.7
4         0    1     58.5     26.5        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
5         0    1     58.5     27.0        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
6         0    1     58.5     26.0        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
7         0    1     59.0     26.5        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
8         0    1     59.0     26.5        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
9         0    1     59.0     27.0        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
10        0    1     59.0     26.5        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
11        0    1     59.0     26.5        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
12        0    1     59.0     27.0        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
13        0    1     59.0     27.0        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
14        0    1     57.5     27.0        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
15        0    1     57.5     27.5        3.8        7.5        4.0        7.5
16        0    1     57.0     27.5        3.3        6.7        4.0        6.7
17        0    1     57.0     27.5        3.3        6.7        4.0        6.7
18        0    1     57.0     27.5        3.3        6.7        4.0        6.7
19        0    1     56.0     27.0        3.3        6.7        4.0        6.7
20        0    1     56.5     28.5        2.9        5.8        4.0        5.8
21        0    1     55.5     26.5        2.9        5.8        4.0        5.8
22        0    1     55.0     26.0        2.9        5.8        4.0        5.8
23        0    1     55.0     26.0        2.9        5.8        4.0        5.8
24        0    1     55.0     26.0        2.9        5.8        4.0        5.8
25        0    1     55.0     26.0        2.9        5.8        4.0        5.8
26        0    1     54.5     25.5        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
27        0    1     54.0     25.5        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
28        0    1     53.5     25.5        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
29        0    1     53.5     25.5        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
30        0    1     54.0     26.5        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
31        0    1     54.0     26.5        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
32        0    1     54.0     26.5        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
33        0    1     56.0     26.5        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
34        0    1     56.0     27.0        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
35        0    1     57.0     27.0        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
36        0    1     58.0     27.0        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
37        1    1     59.0     28.5        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
38        1    1     60.0     29.5        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
39        1    1     59.5     29.5        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
40        1    1     60.0     29.5        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
41        1    1     59.5     29.5        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
42        1    1     59.0     28.0        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
43        1    1     59.5     28.0        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
44        1    1     59.5     28.0        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
45        1    1     59.5     28.5        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
46        1    1     56.0     28.0        2.9        5.8        6.5        5.8
47        1    1     54.0     28.0        2.5        5.0        6.5        5.0
48        1    1     53.0     24.5        2.1        4.2        6.5        4.2
49        1    1     53.0     25.0        2.1        4.2        6.5        4.2
50        1    1     54.0     26.0        2.1        4.2        6.5        4.2
51        1    1     54.5     26.0        2.1        4.2        6.5        4.2
52        1    1     54.5     25.5        2.1        4.2        6.5        4.2
53        1    1     54.0     24.0        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
54        1    1     54.0     24.0        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
55        1    1     55.0     24.0        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
56        1    1     55.0     24.0        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
57        1    1     55.0     24.0        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
58        1    1     55.0     24.5        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
59        1    1     55.0     24.5        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
60        1    1     55.0     25.0        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
61        1    1     55.0     23.5        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
62        1    1     55.0     24.0        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
63        1    1     55.0     23.5        2.1        4.2        6.5        4.2
64        1    1     55.0     23.5        1.7        3.3        6.5        3.3
65        1    1     55.0     22.5        1.7        3.3        6.5        3.3
66        1    1     56.0     25.5        1.3        2.5        6.5        2.5
67        1    1     56.0     25.5        1.3        2.5        6.5        2.5
68        1    1     56.5     25.0        1.3        2.5        6.5        2.5
69        1    1     58.5     29.5        1.3        2.5        6.5        2.5
70        1    1     58.5     28.5        1.3        2.5        6.5        2.5
71        1    1     58.5     28.5        1.3        2.5        6.5        2.5
72        1    1     59.5     29.5        1.3        2.5        6.5        2.5
73        1    1     61.5     33.0        1.3        2.5        6.0        2.5
74        1    1     61.0     33.0        1.3        2.5        6.0        2.5
75        1    1     61.5     32.0        1.7        3.3        6.0        3.3
76        1    1     59.5     32.0        1.7        3.3        6.0        3.3
77        1    1     60.0     32.5        1.7        3.3        6.0        3.3
78        1    1     57.5     32.5        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
79        1    1     58.0     33.0        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
80        1    1     58.5     32.5        2.1        4.2        6.0        4.2
81        1    1     57.5     31.5        2.1        4.2        5.0        4.2
82        1    1     57.5     31.5        2.1        4.2        5.0        4.2
83        1    1     59.0     31.5        2.5        5.0        5.0        5.0
84        1    1     58.5     30.5        2.5        5.0        4.0        5.0
85        0    1     55.5     27.5        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
86        0    1     54.0     27.5        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
87        0    1     53.5     27.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
88        0    1     53.0     27.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
89        0    1     53.0     27.5        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
90        0    1     52.5     27.0        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
91        0    1     50.5     27.5        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
92        0    1     51.5     27.5        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
93        0    1     51.5     27.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
94        0    1     52.0     27.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
95        0    1     52.0     27.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
96        0    1     52.0     28.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
97        0    1     52.5     28.5        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
98        0    1     54.0     28.5        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
99        0    1     54.0     29.0        2.5        5.0        4.0        5.0
100       0    1     53.0     28.0        2.5        5.0        4.0        5.0
101       0    1     52.5     28.0        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
102       0    1     52.5     28.0        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
103       0    1     53.0     28.0        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
104       0    1     53.0     28.0        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
105       0    1     52.5     26.0        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
106       0    1     54.0     26.5        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
107       0    1     53.5     26.5        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
108       0    1     53.5     26.5        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
109       1    1     56.0     29.5        2.1        4.2        5.0        4.2
110       1    1     53.5     27.0        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
111       1    1     53.5     27.0        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
112       1    1     53.5     26.5        2.1        4.2        5.0        4.2
113       1    1     54.0     26.5        2.1        4.2        5.0        4.2
114       1    1     52.5     24.0        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
115       1    1     53.0     24.5        2.1        4.2        5.0        4.2
116       1    1     54.0     26.0        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
117       1    1     54.0     26.0        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
118       1    1     54.5     26.0        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
119       1    1     52.5     24.5        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
120       1    1     52.5     24.5        2.1        4.2        3.5        4.2
121       1    1     54.0     27.5        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
122       1    1     54.0     27.5        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
123       1    1     53.0     28.5        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
124       1    1     53.0     28.5        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
125       1    1     52.5     28.0        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
126       1    1     52.5     27.5        2.1        4.2        4.0        4.2
127       1    1     53.0     28.0        2.1        4.2        4.5        4.2
128       1    1     53.5     28.0        2.5        5.0        4.5        5.0
129       1    1     54.5     28.0        2.5        5.0        4.5        5.0
130       1    1     54.0     26.5        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
131       1    1     53.5     26.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
132       1    1     54.5     26.5        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
133       0    1     55.5     28.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
134       0    1     56.0     28.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
135       0    1     56.0     28.0        2.5        5.0        3.5        5.0
136       0    1     54.5     27.5        2.5        5.8        3.5        5.8
137       0    1     56.0     24.5        2.9        5.8        5.0        5.8
138       0    1     58.5     29.0        2.9        5.8        5.0        5.8
139       0    1     57.5     28.5        2.9        5.8        5.0        5.8
140       0    1     57.0     28.5        2.9        5.8        5.0        5.8
141       0    1     57.0     28.5        2.9        5.8        5.0        5.8
142       0    1     58.0     28.5        2.9        5.8        5.0        5.8
143       0    1     58.0     29.5        2.9        5.8        5.0        5.8
144       0    1     59.0     29.5        2.9        5.8        5.0        5.8
145       0    1     59.0     31.0        2.9        5.8        5.5        5.8
146       0    1     59.0     31.0        2.9        5.8        5.5        5.8
147       0    1     58.5     31.0        2.9        5.8        5.5        5.8
148       0    1     58.5     31.0        2.9        5.8        5.5        5.8
149       0    1     58.5     32.0        2.5        5.0        5.5        5.0
150       0    1     58.0     32.0        2.5        5.0        5.5        5.0
151       0    1     56.8     32.5        2.5        5.0        5.5        5.0
152       0    1     58.3     31.5        3.8        7.5        5.5        7.5
153       0    1     59.0     37.0        0.5        8.5        5.5        9.5
154       0    1     59.2     37.5        1.0        8.5        5.5        9.5
155       0    1     61.0     39.5        0.5        9.0        8.0        9.0
156       0    1     60.5     39.5        0.5        9.0        8.0        9.0
157       0    1     60.0     39.5        0.5        9.0        8.0        9.0
158       0    1     59.2     39.0        0.5        8.5        8.0        9.0
159       0    1     59.5     39.5        0.5        8.5        8.5        9.0
160       0    1     59.5     39.5        0.5        8.5        8.5        9.0
161       0    1     59.5     39.5        0.5        8.5        8.5        9.0
162       0    1     59.2     39.0        0.5        8.0        8.5        9.0
163       0    1     58.7     39.0        0.5        8.0        8.5        9.0
164       0    1     58.5     38.5        0.5        7.5        8.5        9.0
165       0    1     58.0     35.0        1.0        4.0        8.5        8.0
166       0    1     57.0     35.0        1.0        4.0        8.5        8.0
167       0    1     56.2     33.5        0.5        4.0        7.5        8.0
168       0    1     56.5     34.0        1.0        4.0        7.5        8.0
169       0    1     54.7     33.5        1.0        8.5        7.5        6.0
170       0    1     52.7     30.5        1.0        6.0        7.5        6.0
171       0    1     52.7     30.5        1.0        6.0        7.5        6.0
172       0    1     54.0     33.0        1.0        8.5        7.5        6.0
173       0    1     52.1     32.7        0.2        8.5        8.0        6.0
174       0    1     50.8     32.2        0.2        8.0        8.0        6.0
175       0    1     52.1     32.2        0.2        8.0        8.0        6.0
176       0    1     51.9     32.2        0.2        8.0        8.0        6.0
177       0    1     51.7     31.5        1.0        7.0        7.5        6.0
178       0    1     51.5     31.5        1.0        7.0        7.5        6.0
179       0    1     52.7     31.5        1.0        7.0        7.5        6.0
180       0    1     52.5     31.5        1.0        7.0        7.5        6.0
181       0    1     54.5     33.5        1.0        8.5        8.5        3.5
182       0    1     55.5     33.5        1.0        8.5        8.5        3.5
183       0    1     56.7     35.0        1.0        9.0        8.5        3.5
184       0    1     56.2     35.0        1.0        9.0        8.5        3.5
185       0    1     55.5     35.0        1.0        9.0        8.5        3.5
186       0    1     56.2     35.0        1.0        9.0        8.5        3.5
187       0    1     56.7     35.0        1.0        9.0        8.5        3.5
188       0    1     56.0     34.0        1.0        9.0        7.5        3.5
189       0    1     55.0     34.0        1.0        9.0        7.5        3.5
190       0    1     55.5     34.0        1.0        9.0        7.5        3.5
191       0    1     55.2     34.0        1.0        9.0        7.5        3.5
192       0    1     59.0     37.0        1.0        9.0        8.5        3.5
193       0    1     62.2     42.0        1.0        9.5        8.0        8.5
194       0    1     61.8     42.0        1.0        9.5        8.0        8.5
195       0    1     60.2     41.0        1.0        9.5        8.0        8.5
196       0    1     63.7     41.0        1.0        9.5        8.0        8.5
197       0    1     60.2     37.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
198       0    1     64.2     42.0        1.0        9.5        9.0        8.5
199       0    1     63.0     40.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
200       0    1     61.5     38.5        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
201       0    1     61.7     38.5        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
202       0    1     62.0     38.5        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
203       0    1     62.0     38.5        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
204       0    1     62.2     38.5        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
205       0    1     61.5     38.5        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
206       0    1     61.2     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
207       0    1     60.5     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
208       0    1     61.0     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
209       0    1     61.5     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
210       0    1     61.7     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
211       0    1     62.0     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
212       0    1     61.7     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
213       0    1     61.5     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
214       0    1     61.2     38.0        1.0        8.5        8.0        8.5
215       0    1     63.7     40.5        1.0        8.0        9.0        8.5
216       0    1     63.7     40.5        1.0        8.0        9.0        8.5
217       0    1     63.7     40.5        1.0        8.0        9.0        8.5
218       0    1     65.7     43.5        1.0        9.5        8.5        9.5
219       0    1     65.5     43.5        1.0        9.5        8.5        9.5
220       0    1     65.5     43.5        1.0        9.5        8.5        9.5
221       0    1     65.0     43.5        1.0        9.5        8.5        9.5
222       0    1     65.0     43.5        1.0        9.5        8.5        9.5
223       0    1     65.0     43.5        1.0        9.5        8.5        9.5
224       0    1     66.2     43.5        1.0       10.0        9.5        8.0
225       0    1     66.2     43.5        1.0       10.0        9.5        8.0
226       0    1     66.2     43.5        1.0       10.0        9.5        8.0
227       0    1     66.0     44.0        1.0       10.0        9.5        8.5
228       0    1     65.7     44.0        1.0       10.0        9.5        8.5
229       0    1     65.5     43.5        1.0        9.5        9.5        8.5
230       0    1     65.5     43.0        1.0       10.0        9.0        8.5
231       0    1     65.5     43.0        1.0       10.0        9.0        8.5
232       0    1     68.2     43.0        1.0       10.0        9.0        8.5
233       0    1     71.5     44.5        1.0       10.0        9.0        9.5
234       0    1     71.7     44.5        1.0       10.0        9.0        9.5
235       0    1     73.2     44.5        1.0       10.0        9.0        9.5
236       0    1     74.7     44.5        1.0       10.0        9.0        9.5
237       0    1     74.7     44.5        1.0       10.0        9.0        9.5
238       0    1     74.7     44.5        1.0       10.0        9.0        9.5
239       0    1     75.5     45.0        1.0       10.0        9.0       10.0
240       0    1     75.5     45.0        1.0       10.0        9.0       10.0
241       0    1     76.0     45.0        1.0       10.0        9.0       10.0
242       0    1     76.7     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
243       0    1     76.7     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
244       0    1     76.7     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
245       0    1     78.0     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
246       0    1     78.0     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
247       0    1     77.0     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
248       0    1     77.2     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
249       0    1     77.2     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
250       0    1     77.7     44.5        1.0       10.0        8.5       10.0
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data with all existing columns? It doesn’t have to be 200 rows :)

Comment: country year crisis1 cen1 comprisk econrisk econrisk_1 econrisk_2 econrisk_3 econrisk_4 econrisk_5 finrisk finrisk_1 finrisk_2 finrisk_3 finrisk_4 finrisk_5 polrisk polrisk_1 polrisk_2 polrisk_3 polrisk_4 polrisk_5 polrisk_6 polrisk_7 polrisk_8 polrisk_9 polrisk_10 polrisk_11 polrisk_12 dbacba llgdp cbagdp dbagdp pcrdbgdp pcrdbofgdp bdgdp fdgdp bcbd ll_usd
Algeria 198501 0 1 57 25.5 3.299999952 6.699999809 4 6.699999809 10 28 6 6 12 5 2 60 8 7 8 9 9 4 2 5 2 3 2 1 83.70198822 79.03222656 13.90233994 69.17227936 64.14144897 64.14144897 48.03868103 56.09185028 131.7926025 83252.09

Comment: Hi, I can still only include part of my existing columns with only 1 observation as a result of the character limitation. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Algeria 198502 0 1 57 25.5 3.299999952 6.699999809 4 6.699999809 10 28 6 6 12 5 2 60 8 7 8 9 9 4 2 5 2 3 2 1 83.70198822 79.03222656 13.90233994 69.17227936 64.14144897 64.14144897 48.03868103 56.09185028 131.7926025 83252.09
Algeria 198503 0 1 57 25.5 3.299999952 6.699999809 4 6.699999809 10 28 6 6 12 5 2 60 8 7 8 9 9 4 2 5 2 3 2 1 83.70198822 79.03222656 13.90233994 69.17227936 64.14144897 64.14144897 48.03868103 56.09185028 131.7926025 83252.09

Comment: above are the other 2 observations, could you please tell me how many observations will be enough so that I can attach more?

Comment: No need I think. Check the answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
test.bic.surv <- bic.surv(
    x[, 3:ncol(x)],
    x$crisis1, x$cen1, factor.type=FALSE, strict=FALSE, nbest=2000, maxCol=50
)
```

You have to provide maxCol parameter. Default is 30 so it is probably not enough for your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Now it works! Btw, is there an upper-bound for this setting? For example, can I set maxCol=6000? I have 100 variables, each with 60 lag variables.. Thank you again!!:)

Comment: You'll probably hit some memory or complexity limits at some point, and to be honest I don't know much about implementation but I don't there is some hard limit somewhere in the library.